# Accessing a master page field in a Master-Nested Master-Content page set up

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a nested master page set up and am trying to access a field contained in my top level master page in my content page.

I first tried cascading the field down populating it in the nested master page but as this can only be done in the Page_PreRender event it's too late for the Content page to be able to read it.

I'm now therefore setting the MasterType directive of the Content page to point directly to the top level master thereby skipping the nested master:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath ="~/Web/Site.master" %>
```

however I'm getting an error

> Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.web_masterfiles_masterfiles_master'
>   to type 'ASP.web_site_master'.

I've tried casting the variable in the content page but the top level master page class (SiteMaster) cannot be resolved (as the error shows):

```
List<string> usersRoles = (SiteMaster)Master.usersRoles;
```

Is there a way to do this? Alternatively is there a way to use the page loading events differently so that the content page can read fields from the nested master page that have in turn been read from the top level master?